# solution of $(A+\lambda{W})x=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, constraint-programming

Trying to solve system $(A+\lambda{W})x=b$ (derived from the method of Lagrange multipliers)
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ -  the Lagrange multiplier. $A$ - symmetric non-singular matrix. $W$ - square diagonal matrix such $W = P+P^T$.

Primary goal is minimize $\|Fx-g\|^2$ s.t. $x^TPx=c$

I found papper "Eigenvalue and Generalized Eigenvalue Problems: Tutorial" where provided solution for $(A+\lambda{W})x=\textbf{0}$  and called "generalized eigenvalue problem".

Other way for possible solution - write a problem as system of polynomials (in my case it will be system 10 equations of 2th degree polynomials with 10 unknowns) but matlab can't solve it.

Any suggestions about solution?

Comment: Can you give some details about the problem or a sample?  What have you tried?  Why not just row reduction, keeping track of denominators?

Comment: Solve it using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) or by $x = (A+\lambda W)^{-1}b$ if $A+\lambda W$ is invertable.

Comment: $\lambda$ is unknown as well as $x$.

Comment: I solving state estimation problem, $x$ encode gravity vector, velocity, observed point coordinates and some biases. I can solve it closed form, but for increasing solution precision I want to constrain estimated gravity vector magnitude (9.81) so, i build Lagrangian and trying find roots of it gradient. Sure o can solve it in nonlinear optimization way, but i want to try something closed form

Comment: can you diagonalize A, or put it in Jordan form?

Comment: from numerical experement it's not diagonalizable. btw if matrix is diagonalizable what can we do?